# Add two MySql variables together, A Date and a Number with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I would like to add two mysql variables together using php in my website. I would like to take the "Date" and add it with "terms"(which is a set of days:: 30,60,90) to produce "Due_Date".

**Home.php**

```
  $query = mysql_query("select * from Book1");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, rep, Date, Name, P_O, ADDDATE(Date, Terms) AS Due_Date, Terms, GREATEST(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date), 0) AS Aging, Open_Balance from Book1");

?>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Quickbooks Invoices
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="addInvoice.php">Add Invoice</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Quickbook Invoices</h1>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="MyTableBtn">Number of Invoices</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive sortable" id="MyTable">
                        <tr class="header">
                            <td>id</td>
                            <td>Rep</td>
                            <td>Date Services Rendered</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>P_O</td>
                            <td>Due Date</td>
                            <td>Terms</td>
                            <td>Aging</td>
                            <td>Open Balance</td>
                            <td>remove</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


                                $className ="";
                                if ($row['Aging'] >= 45)
                                {
                                    $className="danger";
                                }
                                else if($row['Aging'] >= 25 && $row['Aging'] <= 44)
                                {
                                    $className="warning";
                                }

                                echo "<tr class='$className'>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Rep']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['P_O']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Due_Date']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Terms']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Aging']."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row['Open_Balance']."</td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='deletepage.php?id=" .$row['id']. "' value='" .$row['id']. "' class='btn btn-success'> Paid</a></td>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
```

So it would have to determine the due date, based off the terms set, so 30=30days=1 month from when their invoice went out. so date= 10/23/2015 terms=30 Due_Date would then = 11/23/2015 and then aging would be determined based off the new calculated due_date.

**addInvoice.php**

```
//escape user inputs for security
$rep = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['rep']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Date']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name']);
$P_O = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['P_O']);
$due_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Due_Date']);
$terms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['terms']);
$aging = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['aging']);
$open_balance = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['open_balance']);

//attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO Book1 (Rep, Date, Name, P_O, Due_Date, Terms, Aging, Open_Balance)
VALUES ('$rep', '$date', '$name', '$P_O', 'ADDDATE(Date, Terms) AS $due_date', '$terms', 'GREATEST(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date), 0) AS $aging', '$open_balance')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    header("location: Home.php");
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql." .mysqli_error($link);
}

//close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

The problem now is when I add a new invoice it will calculate the due date perfectly but now it wont calculate the aging. Any help?

Comment: Will terms always be in days??

Comment: yes it will always be in days, in increments of 30 so being 30,60,90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       rep,
       Date,
       Name,
       P_O,
       ADDDATE(Date, Terms) AS DueDate,
       Terms,
       GREATEST(DATEDIFF(NOW(), ADDDATE(Date, Terms)), 0) AS Aging,
       Open_Balance
from   Book1
```

Comment: perfect this is exaclty what i was looking for, i have some invoices with an empty terms, becuase of this it wont present a due date? any way to fix this?

Comment: What would you like due date to be if the terms are empty?

Comment: i would like it to display NULL

Comment: When you say "empty," what value does that equate to in the db? If it means NULL, then DueDate will be NULL when returned from the query. If it is the empty string "", then you can use `ADDDATE(Date, NULLIF(Terms,'')) AS DueDate`

Comment: That code ended up putting all the due_dates as empty. The Terms are empty on some invoices, so its listing Due_date as empty.

Comment: Your code is working great, however i edited the question, this is now causing an error when i add a new invoice, its calculating the due_date just fine but not calculating the aging.

Comment: `GREATEST(DATEDIFF(NOW(), Due_Date), 0)` You can't reference a column by alias in the same query. You'll have to repeat the expression for Due_Date here. Alternatively, you can use a subquery. Also, in the insert, you do not want the `AS ...` column aliases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93202/discussion-between-charles-and-jrd).

Answer (score 1):

Check if that's what you're looking for:

`echo "<td>". date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['Date'] .' +'. $row['Terms'] .' days')) ."</td>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate_postpone_due_date($billingcycle)
{
switch($billingcycle)
{
    case "Monthly":         $months = 1; break;
    case "Quarterly":       $months = 3; break;
    case "Semi-Annually":   $months = 6; break;
    case "Annually":        $months = 12; break;
    case "Biennially":      $months = 24; break;
    case "Triennially":     $months = 36; break;
    default:                $months = 0; break;
}


if ($months == 0)
    return FALSE;    

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$next_due_date = strtotime($today.' + '.$months.' Months');
return date('Y-m-d', $next_due_date);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$NewDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . " $terms"));
echo $NewDate;
```

Comment: im using php to `$query`my database, grab the info and fill a table with the info. How would this be done within the `$query`?